# How to deploy Next.js static export with Nginx? (deep links not working)

Tags: nginx, next.js

I made a next.js export into the `out` folder.

Folder structure is:

- out

  - index.html
  - terms.html
  - privacy.html

I set up nginx to serve files from this folder:

```
server {
    root /var/www/myproject/out;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name myproject.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The main page (index) opens fine. Navigation from within the app to urls like `myproject.com/privacy` works fine. The problem is if I try to open these links directly, it will serve the main page (index) instead of the actual pages, since those urls don't exist in the folder. The only way to open the privacy page directly is adding the html extension to the url: `myproject.com/privacy.html`.

How to configure nginx to serve the actual page `myproject.com/privacy.html` when someone enters the `myproject.com/privacy` url?

Comment: in try_files include $uri.html

Comment: @Nayan bless you my friend, it works as expected. Do you want to create a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure. Added answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Issue is in `try_files`.

As current configuration includes:

- / (which default route to index.html at root path)
- index.html
- /index.html
- test/*.html

To access pages route path name without extension i.e., `/privacy` that format should be included in `try_files` insdie `location /`

Try this:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html /$uri /index.html
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed a 2nd location block because of the way NextJS does ids in the url.  NextJS will have files like `[id].html` or whatever.

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html /$uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~* /(.*)/(\d+)$ {
        try_files $1/[id].html /$1/[id].html /index.html;
    }
```

So I needed the 2nd block to catch urls of the form `/whatever/etc/5` and redirect nginx to `/whatever/etc/[id].html`

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: @PatrickWaweru i may have dropped a slash in the regex before the digits.  Edited.

Comment: I will try it and give you feedback

Answer (score 0):

I tried this configuration and it works like charm.

```
server_name example.com;

root /var/www/example.com/;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html /$uri $uri/ /404.html =404;
}

location ~ ^/[^/]+\.html$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```